# Jquery shake inline element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, shake

I am trying to add a shake effect as a BB code for a forum.  I was hoping to do something like and have it work inline.

```
.shake {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0px 5px;
}

function shake(){
    $(".shake").effect("shake");
    setTimeout("shake()", 100);
}
```

Something along the lines of this.
http://jsfiddle.net/vs5ogbdj/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `wrongly` used callback on `setTiemout`. Use below code instead and it will shake like there is no tomorrow ,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    shake();
});

function shake() {
    $(".shake").effect("shake", {times: 20, distance: 1}, 40);
    setTimeout(shake, 100);
}
```

And for the Design Distortion use,

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
        display:inline;
    }
```

#### See the [Shaking Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs5ogbdj/7/)

Comment: The problem is inline.  It breaks the text.  Look at what it does to the text.  It looks awful inline.

Comment: Ah!! I misunderstood your question.; I thought you need shake effect for long time. Which by the way was not supported in your code.

Comment: Ok, Now i got it all set up. Check it!!